Functional equation proof
I'm stuck with this problem:
Knowing that for $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$
$$f(xy+x+y)=f(xy)+f(x)+f(y)$$ prove that
$$f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$$
What I got so far: f(0)=0 (if x=y=0 then $f(0)=3f(0)$). I tried letting  $x=1$ and $y=1$ leading me to $f(2x+1)+f(2y+1)=2(f(x)+f(y)+f(2))$.  $f(x)=const.$ is obvious contradiction. Tried $f(x)=ax$ and it seems to work fine and it implies the thesis. No idea how to prove it's the only one that works.
